# Multiple Firestore snapshots overwrite each other

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Im checking if firestore arrays contains strings from another array (not Firestore array). Then I place the data in a dictionary

```
 func loadData(){
        for i in 0..<testTable.count {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Ingredients").whereField("compName", arrayContains: testTable[i] ).getDocuments(){
            querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }else if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                if (querySnapshot.isEmpty == false){

                self.ingredientsArray = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap({Ingredients(dictionary: $0.data())})

                    print("\(self.ingredientsArray)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that dictionary keeps the data from only the last snapshot as expected. Is there a way to keep all the data from all the snapshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens as you re-assign the array `self.ingredientsArray` so Replace this

```
 self.ingredientsArray = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap({Ingredients(dictionary: $0.data())})
```

with

```
let res = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap({Ingredients(dictionary: $0.data())})
self.ingredientsArray.append(contentsOf:res)
```

Comment: Oh my God! I tried append so many times but I never thought that its going to be so easy. Thank you so much!!